# Is there any way to show resolutions (width and height) without decimal point in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have Chrome Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) On Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Is there any way for showing width and height in dev tools without a decimal point (For example 857px and not 857.541px)?

[image: Without Precision Chrome]

[image: With Precision Chrome]